# How to disable ofetch auto retry in nuxt 3 usefetch?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

i got a problem while using useFetch composable on nuxt 3. I want the request to fire only once regardless the result of the request.

But i couldn't find a way to do that, it will always do a retry when the request fails.

Is there a way to do that in nuxt 3 useFetch composable?

I've spent hours searching on google but couldn't find any answer. I expect there is a way to do that, Thank You

Comment: See https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch#params , check ofetch retry config instead

Answer (score 0):

In options of usefetch you can false the value of watch parameter

```
options:{
     watch:false,
}
```

watch: watch an array of reactive sources and auto-refresh the fetch result when they change. Fetch options and URL are watched by default. You can completely ignore reactive sources by using watch: false.

See bellow link for more details:
https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch#params

Answer (score 0):

As I check in documentation, it is possible to set retry parameter as false

```
useFetch(url, {retry: false})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to here
About Nuxt oFetch autoRetry
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/23457